# Using Mockito to mock a CLOB from database

Tags: java, oracle, mockito

Wondering if anyone could help or has done something similar. I am trying to mock returning an Oracle CLOB from a custom ClobFactory. I am using the following code to create the CLOB

```
CLOB clob = CLOB.createTemporary(connection, false, CLOB.DURATION_SESSION);
try (final Writer clobWriter = clob.setCharacterStream(1)) {
    clobWriter.write(profile);
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new SQLException(e);
}
return clob;
```

And my test I have set up the following mocks

```
@Mock OracleDataSource        dataSource;
@Mock CreateProfileParameters parameters;
@Mock ClobDBAccess            clobDbAccess;
@Mock OracleConnection        connection;

@Mock ClobFactory clobFactory;
@Mock CLOB        clob;
@Mock Writer      clobWriter;

....

when(dataSource.getConnection()).thenReturn(connection);
when(CLOB.getDBAccess(connection)).thenReturn(clobDbAccess);
when(clobDbAccess.createTemporaryClob(connection, false, CLOB.DURATION_SESSION, (short) 0)).thenReturn(clob);
when(CLOB.createTemporary(connection, false, CLOB.DURATION_SESSION)).thenReturn(clob);
when(ClobFactory.getClob(connection, dataString)).thenReturn(clob);
```

But I keep getting a NullPointerException each time the test is run, pointing to the second line -

```
Stacktrace was: java.lang.NullPointerException
at oracle.sql.CLOB.getDBAccess(CLOB.java:1525) ...
```

Has anyone tried something like this before? Or am I missing out another object that I should be mocking?

Answer (score 1):

The method `CLOB.getDBAccess(connection)` is a static method of the `CLOB` class and as such cannot be mocked with Mockito.

You can mock statics with [**Powermock**](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen the `getDBAccess` method of the `CLOB` class before.  But looking at the above, it seems to me that it's probably `final`, which means you can't stub it with Mockito.  I would suggest using a real `CLOB`, instead of a mock one.  It's usually a bad idea to mock value objects, and a `CLOB` is definitely a value object.

Comment: I have tried using a value object but I still get the same exception thrown - my getClob method is a static call, if it was an instance method call would this possibly work?